# Generate ffmpeg thumbnail from stream in Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

Im using node.js together with ffmpeg to receive an rtmp-stream and output this into m3u8-format.

```
[ '-y',
  '-fflags',
  'nobuffer',
  '-analyzeduration',
  '1000000',
  '-i',
  'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/ANMZJ2ZRUiMhKaAoygRXwAfHe',
  '-c:v',
  'copy',
  '-c:a',
  'aac',
  '-f',
  'tee',
  '-map',
  '0:a?',
  '-map',
  '0:v?',
  '-y',
  '-an',
  '[hls_time=10:hls_list_size=0]./media/live/ANMZJ2ZRUiMhKaAoygRXwAfHe/SX3otgDdf6/index.m3u8|' ]
```

Together with this functionality I would also like to output a thumbnail. I tried to do this using the following format but without success.

```
[ '-y',
  '-fflags',
  'nobuffer',
  '-analyzeduration',
  '1000000',
  '-i',
  'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/ANMZJ2ZRUiMhKaAoygRXwAfHe',
  '-c:v',
  'copy',
  '-c:a',
  'aac',
  '-f',
  'tee',
  '-map',
  '0:a?',
  '-map','0:v?',
  '-y',
  '-an',
  '-vf' ,
  'fps=1',
  'C:/Users/media/out.png'
  '[hls_time=10:hls_list_size=0]./media/live/ANMZJ2ZRUiMhKaAoygRXwAfHe/SX3otgDdf6/index.m3u8|' ]
```

The way I send this information to ffmpeg is by

```
this.ffmpeg_exec = spawn(ffmpeg_path, args);
```

Im unable to create a thumbnail using this approach. Does anyone know the problem/solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a log of extra arguments in the second command! You really only need the input, number of frames, and output.

```
[ '-i',
  'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/ANMZJ2ZRUiMhKaAoygRXwAfHe',
  '-frames:v',
  '1',
  'C:/Users/media/out.png'
]
```

Docs for `-frames:v` 
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options

Comment: You are correct, that outputs an image! But, then the output to HLS (.m3u8) is not working. Can this be done also?

Comment: This needs to be run as a separate command because it is only requesting one frame (you obviously need more than that for the stream to work)

Answer (score 0):

`fluent-ffmpeg` support stream input and output   :

```js
var FfmpegCommand = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var ffmpeg = FfmpegCommand();
  ffmpeg.input(stream)
  .seekInput("00:00:01.000")
  .outputFormat("image2")
  .pipe(res,{end:true});
```